# Boost compilation error in policy.hpp

Tags: c++

For my project, I am trying to upgrade the boost library from 1.39 to 1.58.

While compiling, I get these errors:

> home/kunehah/third_party/boost_1_58/prefix/include/boost/math/policies/policy.hpp:708:17: error: expected identifier before 'double'
>   /home/kunehah/third_party/boost_1_58/prefix/include/boost/math/policies/policy.hpp:708:17: error: two or more data types in declaration of 'parameter'
>   /home/kunehah/third_party/boost_1_58/prefix/include/boost/math/policies/policy.hpp:709:8: error: no default argument for 'Policy'
>   /home/kunehah/third_party/boost_1_58/prefix/include/boost/math/policies/policy.hpp:715:32: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<, class Policy> struct boost::math::policies::evaluation'
>   /home/kunehah/third_party/boost_1_58/prefix/include/boost/math/policies/policy.hpp:715:32: error:   expected a constant of type '', got 'float'

And my `policy.hpp` file is below:

```
//
// Traits class to handle internal promotion:
//
template <class Real, class Policy>//**line 708**
struct evaluation
{
   typedef Real type;
};

template <class Policy>
struct evaluation<float, Policy>//line 715**
{
   typedef typename mpl::if_<typename Policy::promote_float_type, double, float>::type type;
};

template <class Policy>
struct evaluation<double, Policy>
{
   typedef typename mpl::if_<typename Policy::promote_double_type, long double, double>::type type;
};

#ifdef BOOST_NO_LIMITS_COMPILE_TIME_CONSTANTS

template <class Real>
struct basic_digits : public mpl::int_<0>{ };
template <>
struct basic_digits<float> : public mpl::int_<FLT_MANT_DIG>{ };
template <>
struct basic_digits<double> : public mpl::int_<DBL_MANT_DIG>{ };
template <>
struct basic_digits<long double> : public mpl::int_<LDBL_MANT_DIG>{ };
```

Kindly help me in understanding these errors.

Comment: please post YOUR code as a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which produces the error messages

Comment: What compiler are you using ?

Comment: It looks like you have an evil definition along the lines of `#define Real double`. Find that, and remove it with extreme prejudice.